How to Navigate inside a folder with Sharepoint API?
I'm new to Sharepoint API and when I hit this API https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe
It returns me list of all the files and folders shared with me in following format
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.driveItem)",
    "value": [
        {
            "createdDateTime": "2024-06-20T12:23:32Z",
            "id": "idValue",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2024-06-20T12:23:32Z",
            "name": "nameValue",
            "webUrl": "webUrlValue",
            "size": 0,
            "lastModifiedBy": {
                "user": {
                   details
                }
            },
          
            "folder": {
                "childCount": 1
            },
            "remoteItem": {
                "createdDateTime": "2024-06-20T12:23:32Z",
                "id": "idValue",
                "lastModifiedDateTime": "2024-06-20T12:23:32Z",
                "name": "NameOfFile",
                "size": 0,
                "webDavUrl": "webDavUrlValue",
                "webUrl": "weburlValue",
                "fileSystemInfo": {
                    "createdDateTime": "2024-06-20T12:23:32Z",
                    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2024-06-20T12:23:32Z"
                },
                "folder": {
                    "childCount": 1
                },
                "lastModifiedBy": {
                    "user": {
                        "email": "emailValue",
                        "id": "samepIDValue",
                        "displayName": "Sample Name"
                    }
                },
                "parentReference": {
                    "driveType": "business",
                    "driveId": "driveIdValue",
                    "id": "idValue",
                    "siteId": "siteIdValue"
                },
                "shared": {
                    "scope": "users",
                    "sharedDateTime": "2024-06-20T12:23:53Z",
                    "sharedBy": {
                        "user": {
                            "email": "name",
                            "id": "id",
                            "displayName": "displayNameValue"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sharepointIds": {
                    "listId": "listIdValue",
                    "listItemId": "listItemIdValue",
                    "listItemUniqueId": "listItemUniqueIdValue",
                    "siteId": "siteIdValue",
                    "siteUrl": "site_URL",
                    "tenantId": "tenantIdValue",
                    "webId": "webIdValue"
                }
            }
        },
    { rest of files}
    ]
    }

I want to cd into this OneDrive folder and access and upload items here. How can i do it?
I've done some research but still can't figure out how to access contents of specific folders that were shared with me.
I tried everything I can but none of them seems to work, there's not much content on Microsoft official docs on how to acccess contents of sharedWithMe files using API.
On chatGPT and other platforms its showing me that if I hit this (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{folderId}/children)  then it'll work even for sharedWithMe files but this doesn't seems to work, maybe I'm picking some wrong value as folder id.

You can use remoteItem.id and remoteItem.parentReference.driveId in the following request to access shared file/folder
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{remoteItem.parentReference.driveId}/items/{remoteItem.id}

But if the folder is shared with you, it does not guarantee that you can upload items here.
Check the doc how to upload a file:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#to-upload-a-new-file
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0
